# Have I found a big difference between using the short form and the long form of a pure function?

Tags: pure-function

By referring to the *Mathematica* documentation, I learned to use `##2` to represent all the arguments but the first one. This is a brief way to represent a pattern matching all arguments but the first one. However, how can I do the same thing in the long `Function[args. body]` form?

For example, `{##2}& @@ f[x1, x2, x3, x4]` will give `{x2, x3, x4}`. Unfortunately, `Function[{u1, u2}, {u2}] @@ f[x1, x2, x3, x4]` only gives `{x2}`.

I think this occurs because the long form does not interally contain pattern matching functionality, although I find this hard to believe. So my question is whether the long form really ignores the functionality of pattern matching?

In general, are these two pure function forms identical in every aspect? That is, is the short form is just a shortcut for the long form?

Comment: `Function[{u1,u2}, {u2}]` is equivalent to `{#2} &`, yes. I don't know of any "named argument" equivalent of `SlotSequence[]`.

Comment: "Identical in every aspect" — No, because with the `Function` form, you can set attributes for pure functions when defining them (using the 3rd argument). BTW, only `&` is `Function`. `#n` is just `Slot`, denoting the nth argument (and `##n` is `SlotSequence` for nth argument onwards), so you can actually do `Function[, {##2}]@{x1, x2, x3, x4}`

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks! `Function [x, {##2 & @@ x}]@f[x1, x2, x3, x4]` works, although the key to give expected result is due to `##2 &` again. BTW, can I reproduce the result by only applying the `Function[]` form?

Comment: @Life Well... it depends on what you'd consider an "answer". For instance, how about: `Function[, Function[, {##2}] @@ #]@f[x1, x2, x3, x4]` or `Function[, Function[, {##2}] @@ Level[#, 1]]@f[x1, x2, x3, x4]` or `Function[, Rest@Level[#, 1]]@f[x1, x2, x3, x4]`?

Comment: Actually, if you're not using the attribute argument of `Function[]`, you can get by with just one argument, without the need for a null first argument; thus, `Function[Rest[Level[#, 1]]] @ f[x1, x2, x3, x4]` or `Function[Function[{##2}] @@ Level[#, 1]] @ f[x1, x2, x3, x4]` work nicely.

Comment: To drive home the fact that `&` is the shorthand form of `Function[]`, ponder on the result of `FullForm[{#} &]`, among other things.

Comment: You should also ponder on `FullForm[{##2} &]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I seem to recall an earlier question addressing this specific aspect (is there a `##` equivalent for named parameters) but I cannot find it.  Nevertheless...

I echo Leonid's answer that there are important differences between pure functions using `Slot` and/or `SlotSequence` and named parameters.  A primary one is the automatic renaming that occurs with the latter; see:
[Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/enforcing-correct-variable-bindings-and-avoiding-renamings-for-conflicting-varia/20776#20776).

A simple illustration is creating a function that creates a `Function`:

```
f1 = Function[stuff, Function[{x}, stuff]][x^2]

f2 = Function[stuff, stuff &][#^2]
```

> ```
> Function[{x$}, x^2]
>
> #1^2 &
> ```

Notice that `f1` is broken because `x` has been silently replaced with `x$` -- this can be desirable behavior but it can also prevent exactly what you intend as is the case here.

As noted in comments the internal form of `&` is actually `Function`, though it is usually not entered that way when using `#` or `##`:

```
Head[{#, ##2} &]

FullForm[{#, ##2} &]
```

> ```
> Function
>
> Function[List[Slot[1],SlotSequence[2]]]
> ```

There is an undocumented syntax for `Function`: if the first argument is `Null` you can use the third parameter (attributes) along with `Slot`:

```
Function[Null, Hold[##], HoldAll][2 + 2, Sqrt[4]]
```

> ```
> Hold[2 + 2, Sqrt[4]]
> ```

`Null` may of course be entered implicitly, e.g.:

```
Function[, ff @ ##2][1, 2, 3, 4]
```

> ```
> ff[2, 3, 4]
> ```

Comment: Thanks@Mr.Wizard. I wonder how can these undocumented syntax be learned. I am a noob learning from Leonid's note and the built-in documentation. This is the knowledge that I can learn so far. BTW, SE is a good university for learning.

Comment: @Life You're welcome.  I learned this particular syntax from Leonid here on StackExchange (StackOverflow, more specifically).  This site is the best resource I have found but if you have the interest there are many other sources as well; a huge list is compiled [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/121).  Also, while I find this site easier to participate in the [MathGroup Archive](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/) is still an excellent resource that should not be overlooked.

Comment: Thanks again! StackOverflow seems to be a melting pot for Computer-Language-based problems.

Comment: And impressed by `Evaluate[ ]`. It totally destroys the sequence of rules transformation held by HoldAll attributes. Simply regard the output form of `Evaluate[ ]` as `Head`'s argument.

Answer (score 8):

FWIW, I disagree with the answers which state that `Function` with named arguments and `Function` expressed using slots (`#`) are the same thing. Please see the first part of [this answer of mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/711/with-versus-function/744#744) for a partial list of differences.

The main difference I want to stress here is that `Function`-s with named arguments are true (albeit leaky) lexical scoping constructs, while `Function`s using slots are not quite (which is why, in particular, they can not be non-trivially nested).

Other technical differences such as support for arbitrary number of arguments for slot-based functions and its lack for functions with named arguments, etc. were mentioned in other answers.

Comment: Thanks! I also noticed `#` and `&` form cannot be easily nested without applying the functionality from `With`. In the example you mentioned<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920194/using-nested-slots>, I hope `With[{x = #1}, Array[#1^#2 == x &, {x, x}]] &` will be an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just to get an answer on record, the answer to your question is "no".

The correct long form of `{##2} & @@ f[x1, x2, x3, x4]` is `Function[{SlotSequence[2]}] @@ f[x1, x2, x3, x4]`. Both give `{x2, x3, x4}`.