# Can we make a faster Boole implementation?

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction, core-language

I just learned about Mr. Wizard's very efficient code here.

```
list=RandomChoice[{True,False},10^6];
AbsoluteTiming[l2=Developer`ToPackedArray@With[{True=1,False=0},Evaluate@list];]
(*{0.066533,Null}*)
```

Compare that to Boole.

```
AbsoluteTiming[l3=Boole[list];]
l2===l3
(*{0.262770,Null}*)
(* True *)
```

It seems we can make a faster Boole. I tried to use the code above to do that, but it doesn't work.

```
boole[list_]:=Developer`ToPackedArray@With[{True=1,False=0},Evaluate@list];
list={True,True,False,True,False};
boole[list]
(*{True,True,False,True,False}*)
```

Why doesn't boole above work, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: I suggest making the question explicit in the title (you're using an existing implementation and it doesn't work, rather than asking for possible implementations) --

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is the automatic module variable renaming that happens with [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With). You can use [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracePrint) to see this:

```
TracePrint[boole[list], _With]
```

> With[{True\$=1,False\$=0},{True,True,False,True,False}]
>
> {True, True, False, True, False}

One idea to circumvent this renaming is to use a pure function:

```
Clear[boole]
boole = Function[Developer`ToPackedArray @ With[{True = 1, False = 0}, #]];
```

Then:

```
boole[list]
```

> {1, 1, 0, 1, 0}

Comment: Thank you. Wizard and Carl are both WL experts. I am using version 10. Is the With[{True=1,False-0} ,...] trick faster than Boole in version 11.3 ?

Comment: With 11.3 on linux `boole` order 10 times faster.

Answer (score 8):

See [Using With to scope over pure functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34345/121), then try:

```
boole[list_] := With @@ Hold[{True = 1, False = 0}, list] // Developer`ToPackedArray
```